# Use Browser is missing settings like "Private" & "NewSession" in the Modern Design

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

For me that's a huge step back. The new `Use Browser` is missing settings like `Private` & `NewSession` in the Modern Design. So it's not possible to open Chrome in private mode anymore. So currently the only workaround is to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+N` as Chrome shortcut:

[image]

But for me that does not sound like a good solution as browsers can swap that hotkey or having different.

So before without the Modern Design is was possible to set incognito mode in `Open Browser`:

[image]

So why is that feature gone in the Modern Design rework? How to get it back without the workaround and still using the Modern Design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround that already allows the `incognito` mode now in Chrome:

1. Add `Application/Browser`
2. Add new Chrome `Application` to the `Object Repository` (or click `Indicate application ...`)
3. Now do NOT create a screen (if the Create screen window is now opened close it)
4. Select the `Use Browser Chrome` and go to property `Unified Application Target > Arguments`
5. Type in `--incognito`
6. Click on the Burger menu of `Use Browser Chrome`
7. In the dropdown select `Add Screen to Object Repository`
8. Create the `Screen` now

All done. When you now check `Use Browser Chrome` for the `Unified Application Target > Arguments` it should still say `--incognito`.

Answer (score 1):

`Private` coming 21.4

`New session` is gone forever because it was targeting IE only, which is out of support